# Probability rules help

Tags: probability

The question is a die is rolled six times. What is the probability that $1,2,3,4,5,6$ will appear in that order?

My question is what formula would you use to solve this because I know that when order matters you use permutations but how would you apply that formula to this question?

Also can you do $\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{6}$? If so, why?

Or do you use $\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{5}\times\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{1}$? If so, why?

Another question is  a single die is rolled 6 times. What is the probability that $1,2,3,4,5,6$ will appear, but in no special order?

How could the combination formula be applied to this? (order does not matter).

Would you do $\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{6}$? If so, why? or $\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{5}\times\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{1}$? If so, why?

Answer (score 3):

For the first scenario, you want an exact result for every roll. Only one of the 6 possibilities is valid for each roll. So yes, you could do $\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^6$

For the second scenario, your first roll will produce a number. You don't care what this number is, and there are 6 possibilities. The second roll has 5 possibilities out of 6 that you desire. The next has 4, and so on. So you get

$$\left(\frac{6}{6}\right)\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)\left(\frac{3}{6}\right)\left(\frac{2}{6}\right)\left(\frac{1}{6}\right) = \frac{6!}{6^6}$$

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to think about this:

1.) The probability of an event $E$ is
$$
P(E)=\frac{\text{# of ways $E$ happens}}{\text{# of ways anything happens}}
$$
So how many ways can the six rolls come up as 1,2,3,4,5, and 6 exactly? Obviously there is only one way for this to happen, so
$$
\text{# of ways event happens} = 1.
$$
How many ways can anything happen? There are 6 dice and each one has six possible outcomes and the outcome of one die has no effect on the other dice, so by the multiplication principle for independent events we have
$$
\text{# of ways anything happens} = 6\cdot6\cdot6\cdot6\cdot6\cdot6=6^6=46,656.
$$
Thus
$$
P(E)=\frac{\text{# of ways event happens}}{\text{# of ways anything happens}}=\frac{1}{46,656}
$$

2.) Each event has a $\dfrac{1}{6}$ probability of occurring and they have to happen in the order 1,2,3,4,5,6 so
$$
P(E)=\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}=\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^6
$$

Observe that
$$
P(E)=\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^6=\frac{1}{6^6}=\frac{1}{46,656}
$$
just like we saw earlier.

Your other answer is incorrect because 
$$
\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1}
$$
is assuming that rolling a 1 on the first dice (prob = 1/6) makes it impossible to roll a 1 on the second die (thus prob = 1/5) and that rolling a 1 and 2 on the first two dice makes getting either a 1 or 2 on the third die impossible (thus prob = 1/4), etc...

Rolling dice are independent events and so the outcome of any one dice is not influenced by the outcome on any of the other dice!